# Pytorch tensor changing colors

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I would appreciate any help on that.

Why after putting tensor of 3d (image) into 4d tensor, the image colors changed.

```
p = "path/to/image"
p = Image.open(p)
p = transforms.PILToTensor()(p)

transforms.ToPILImage()(p).show()  # ok  (left pic)
temp = torch.zeros(4, p.size()[0], p.size()[1], p.size()[2])
temp[0] = p
transforms.ToPILImage()(temp[0]).show()  # not ok  (right pic)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The reason is that the first tensor `p` is an integer tensor and values range between 0 - 255. The second image is a float tensor and the values range between 0.0 - 255.0. `imshow` function expects integer values between 0 - 255 or float values between 0 - 1, you can read more [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html).

To fix this problem, you have two options either add the `dtype=torch.uint8` when you define a `temp` tensor or divide the values of the tensor by 255 to scale it between 0 -1.

```
# cell 1
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms
import torch
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

p = Image.open("pi.png")
p = transforms.PILToTensor()(p).permute(1, 2, 0)
plt.imshow( p )     #ok 

# cell 2
temp = torch.zeros(4, p.size()[0], p.size()[1], p.size()[2], dtype=torch.uint8)
temp[0] = p
plt.imshow(temp[0]) # or you can use plt.imshow(temp[0]/255)
```